# C# TCP socket high network usage

Tags: c#

I have the following code that sends eight images per second to a connected TCP client:

```
static void HandleServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server is starting...");
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

            Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                newsock.Bind(ipep);
                newsock.Listen(10);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");

                Socket client = newsock.Accept();
                IPEndPoint newclient = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
                Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}",
                                newclient.Address, newclient.Port);
            HandleImage(client, newsock);

        }


        private static void HandleImage(Socket client, Socket s)
        {
            int sent;
            int imageCount = 0;
            double totalSize = 0;
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {

                    Image bmp = getImage();
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    // Save to memory using the bmp format
                    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    byte[] bmpBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    bmp.Dispose();
                    ms.Close();

                    sent = SendVarData(client, bmpBytes);
                    imageCount++;
                    totalSize += sent;
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent " + sent + " bytes");
                    Thread.Sleep(125);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception catched, probably an interrupted connection. Restarting server...");
                s.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Transferred {0} images with a total size of {1}", imageCount, totalSize);
                Console.WriteLine("Average JPEG size: " + totalSize / imageCount + " byte");
                HandleServer();
            }
        }
        private static int SendVarData(Socket s, byte[] data)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int size = data.Length;
            int dataleft = size;
            int sent;

            byte[] datasize = new byte[4];
            datasize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
            sent = s.Send(datasize);

            while (total < size)
            {
                sent = s.Send(data, total, dataleft, SocketFlags.None);
                total += sent;
                dataleft -= sent;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
    }
```

Each image has an average size of 0.046 megabyte, which brought me to a calculated network bandwith of 0.37 megabyte per second for eight images per second.
I monitored the applicaton in the Windows 10 task manager and saw, that the network usage goes up to 35-40 Mbps after two to three seconds.
Could this be in context with my source code?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like you're sending 4 bytes of data per second, which seems to be very very low to me. I expect the overhead of each send operation is probably at least ten times that amount. Also the network usage may be measuring megabits instead of megabytes, so you'd have to divide by 8.

Comment: That code looks fine to me.

Comment: @NibblyPig no, it is sending 4 bytes of header (length prefix), then `size` bytes of payload - and all of that 8 times a second; code looks legit to me; there *are* lots of things it could do better, but... it should work fine and should be sending the expected amounts.

Comment: *network usage goes up to 35-40 Mbps after two to three seconds* how do you know this is your program doing this? If I'm reading it right you seem to be assuming [correlation == causation](https://xkcd.com/552/)

Comment: My mistake. Perhaps the latter part of my comment explains it - and perhaps you have to halve it as well if it's sending to localhost?

Comment: Wasn't sure if the network monitor would count loopback traffic. Well. I'm out of ideas then!

Comment: @Marc Garvell what could I Do better?

Comment: @Liam I am sending to another IP address

Comment: @ItFreak oh, that's a full day topic! Immediate thoughts: async IO (don't use thread-per-client) is a biggie; use of `GetBuffer()` rather than `ToArray()` avoids a potentially huge array allocation, but then you need to ensure you track the `.Length` (the result of `.GetBuffer()` is an *oversized* array); you could also re-use a `MemoryStream` over and over, calling `.SetLength(0)` on it each time, to avoid lots more allocations. If it is high usage, I'd probably also look at "pipelines", but you probably don't need this here.

Comment: You could also use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the traffic to get actual numbers instead of relying on task manager. With Wireshark you should be able to filter out any additional "noise".

Comment: There can be retransmissions which may cause increasing of traffic to identify such cases you can use Wireshark.

Comment: Do not get MegaBytes and MegaBits mixed up.  MBPS is bits which is approximately 10 times larger than bytes.